# Typescript: Equivalent of linq .GroupBy(key => key.IdItem).Select(item => item.Single());

Tags: javascript, linq, typescript

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `.GroupBy(key => key.IdItem).Select(item => item.Single());` from linq to typescript.

What I've tried:

```
let parents = value.reduce((parents, parent) => ({
            ...ubc,
            [parent.IdItem]: [...(parents[u.IdItem] || []), parent],
        }), {}) as Array<ItemsViewModel>;


Array.prototype.map.call(parents, parent => {
    if (parents.length > 1) {
        throw new Error('The input sequence contains more than one element');
    }
    else if (!parents.length) {
        throw new Error('The input sequence is empty');
    }
    return parent[0];
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are reducing to an object, it's not an array.

Comment: Mind providing a sample example of `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like this --

```
let parentsById = 
  value.reduce((dict, parent) => {
    let { IdItem } = parent;

    dict[IdItem] = dict[IdItem] || [];
    dict[IdItem].push(parent);
    return dict;
    }, {});

let result = 
  Object.keys(parentsById)
    .map(k => {
      let parents = parentsById[k];
      if(parents.length !== 1) { throw new Error("Must contain a single item"); }
      return parents[0];
      });
```

---

Also, if you simply want unique parents, you can use a hashet of seen IDs --

```
let result = [];
let seenIds = {};

for(let parent of value) {
  let { IdItem } = parent;
  if(!seenIds[IdItem]) {
    result.push(parent);
    seenIds[IdItem] = true;
  }
}
```